# In rails, can I create a product with multiple relationships all on one save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a product model that has a relationship like so:

`has_many :product_images`
`has_many :product_specs`

The relationships are working fine, and I am happy about that.

When I create my new product, I have the controller set to save the product_image and the product_spec after the product is created. The problem is: *I need multiple specs and product images*. Is there a way to add multiple product_images and multiple product_specs in the form for a new product and have them all be created at once when the product is created? Also, the user would decide how many images and specs they need to add.

I appreciate any advice anyone has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read rubyonrails api deeper a bit ;) [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end
```

You can now set or update attributes on an associated post model through the attribute hash.

For each hash that does not have an id key a new record will be instantiated, unless the hash also contains a _destroy key that evaluates to true.

```
params = { :member => {
  :name => 'joe', :posts_attributes => [
    { :title => 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
    { :title => 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen' },
    { :title => '', :_destroy => '1' } # this will be ignored
  ]
}}

member = Member.create(params['member'])
member.posts.length # => 2
member.posts.first.title # => 'Kari, the awesome Ruby     documentation browser!'
member.posts.second.title # => 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen'
```

Comment: I try to, I just didn't know where to look. :) Good to know about the attributes hash, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. Form implementation is up to you. A gem or your personal implementation might be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the `nested form` gem by Ryan Bates. It is exactly what you are looking for.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form).
The Railscasts for it is [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).